# Annotation Scaling to ensure fixed text size

Tags: qgis, annotation

Is there a way to fix the scale of annotations such that when I zoom in or out of the map canvas the annotations can still be visible at the same size?

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: @ Kadir Sahbaz Qgis